# how to handle a unhandled key code qt android

Tags: android, qt

im trying to handle when a button is pressed but isn't handled by QT

on main qml file have this code

> ```
> Keys.onPressed: {
>         console.log(event.key);
>
>         if(event.key === 302){
>             console.log("hello world");
>         }
>     }
> ```

but on console show me the next error:

> bDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !
>
> W libDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !
>
> W libDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !
>
> W libDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !
>
> W libDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !
>
> W libDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !
>
> W libDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !
>
> W libDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !
>
> W libDroidStar_arm64-v8a.so: Unhandled key code  302 !

Comment: oh yea... i solve this but in really weird way... so i just switch QT for Java... toocomplex to use native stuffs or handle this kind of stuffs, well... in my case. @Fausto01